# Does presto support insert overwrite into hive table?

Tags: sql, hive, airflow, presto, trino

I am trying to insert data into a partioned table. I am using PrestoSqlOperator ( airflow DAG) to run a presto/trino SQL query.

I am able to insert data into table using command

Insert into table......

But if I am trying to use below command

Insert overwrite table .....

It's throwing error.

Please help me with the correct statement.

I have also tried to drop the partition, but did not get much success.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT OVERWRITE feature was added in Trino v 419

```
INSERT OVERWRITE hive.test2.insert_test SELECT * FROM tpch.sf1.customer;
```

Previous implementation is:

```
SET SESSION hive.insert_existing_partitions_behavior='OVERWRITE';
INSERT INTO hive.test2.insert_test SELECT * FROM tpch.sf1.customer;
```

See more details https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/11602
https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues?page=2&q=+insert+overwrite
and https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues?page=2&q=+insert+overwrite